# java syntax of addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher())

Tags: java, android, interface

i have a newbie question. Can someone explain what type of java syntax is in code like this. I've googled and but I dont seem to understand how is this an implementation of TextWatcher in anonymus class, (or something like that). All implementations I've seen so far had a keyword implements in a class definiton but this one does not. Any explanations are welcome (I know what this code does and how do I use it, the understanding of syntax is my problem.) If you could rewrite it in a equivalent way would also be great. Thanks

```
mObjectOfEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                public void onTextChanged(parameters) {}

            public void beforeTextChanged(parameters) {}

            public void afterTextChanged(parameters) {}
        });
```

Comment: have you checked this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you implement an interface (or extend a class) with an anonymous class, you don't give a name to that class, so there's no place where you can write `X implements Y` (since there is no X). That's what anonymous means. This is exactly what happens in your example.

`addTextChangedListener` expects an instance that implements `TextWatcher`. In the example, the implementation appears inline, as an anonymous class, that implements all the methods of that interface.

Your example can be replaced with equivalent code using a regular class that implements that interface :

```
public class TextWatcherImpl implements TextWatcher 
{
    public void onTextChanged(parameters) {}

    public void beforeTextChanged(parameters) {}

    public void afterTextChanged(parameters) {}
}
```

Then, you can use that class this way :

```
TextWatcherImpl impl = new TextWatcherImpl ();
mObjectOfEditText.addTextChangedListener(impl);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think in 99% of the cases you want to update a `String` as the user types.
This totally works fine:

```
String string;

mObjectOfEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        public void onTextChanged(...) {}

        public void beforeTextChanged(...) {}

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable e) {
            string = e.toString();
        }
});
```

But instead of writing empty `onTextChanged`s and `beforeTextChanged`s over and over again you could create an abstract class:

```
abstract class LightTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {
    @Override public final void beforeTextChanged(...) {}
    @Override public final void onTextChanged(...) {} 
}
...
mObjectOfEditText.addTextChangedListener(new LightTextWatcher() {
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable e) {
        string = e.toString();
    }
});
```

Now if you have many `TextView`s (or `EditText`s which are `TextView`s)  you have a lot less verbose code with the second variant.

Answer (score 0):

see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20824634/android-on-text-change-listener) and this [example](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/06/android-edittext-text-change-listener.html), actually you do it like this :

```
  EditText myTextBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myTextBox);
  myTextBox.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

  public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
     }

 public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, 
    int count, int after) {
     }

  public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, 
    int before, int count) {
    TextView myOutputBox = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myOutputBox);
    myOutputBox.setText(s);
     }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

***1. Basic***

```
TextWatcher tw = new TextWatcher();
```

***2. Child class:***

```
private class MyTextWatcher extends/implements TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(parameters) {
        ...
    }

}

TextWatcher tw = new MyTextWatcher();
```

***3. With anonymous class:***

```
public class Main {

final StringBuilder sb = ...;
TextWatcher tw = new TextWatcher() {

    {
        sb.append("TW: ");
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(parameters) {
        ... sb ... Main.this ...
    }

};
```

So an anonymous class does not need a name and is defined at its declaration. Also newly introduced public methods or fields still will not be accessible, as the instance variable is of the base class/interface. The anonymous class can use *effectively* `final` local variables, fields and this of the surrounding class (`Main.this` here). *(The variable must be effectively final because a new variable `sb` is made in the class, as the variable scope/life-time of sb will vary. And the language designers found it better to let those two variables always hold the same value.)*

Above an initializer block is used `{ ... }` as a replacement for a constructor.