# Edittext text input listener

Tags: java, android, xml, android-edittext

Am developing an android chat application. Everything works well but except for one thing; I want to set the visibility of a layout to gone and then set a different layout to visible when user starts typing in the edittext like the one implemented on whatsapp.
But I cant seem to figure it out. 
Any help will be appreciated

Basically, what I want to do is set the visibility of a layout which contains an image button to upload image to gone and then show a layout which contains an image button to send the message or text in the edittext to visible when the user starts typing

Comment: Use text change listener http://stackoverflow.com/a/20824665/2146871

Comment: @Julius your reference seems quite good. ll try and see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [TextChangedListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#addTextChangedListener(android.text.TextWatcher)). With help of the [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) you should be able to run commands when the input changes.

Please describe in more detail, if you need further assistance.

Comment: what I want to do is set the visibility of a layout which contains an image button to upload image to gone and then show a layout which contains an image button to send the message or text in the edittext to visible when the user starts typing

Comment: Then the TextChangedListener (linked above) is exactly what you need. Check in the listener if the text's length is greather than 0 and apply the desired changes to the layout.

Answer (score 2):

Can you explain in detail? 
Do you wan edit text to come up when keyboard is hoped up. 
then use below in your manifest.

```
<activity
        android:name=".Activityname"

        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
```

If not, then please explain your question in more detail