# Subtract at runtime in Android

Tags: android, background-subtraction

I have three edittext named et1,et2,et3. I want to subract et1 and et2 and show the answer in et3. But this should be done without clicking any button. As soon as I write values in et1 and et2, the calculations have to be done and displayed in et3.

Thank You,
Spandan Joshi

Comment: did you try any code?

Comment: As the answer suggests, just try and find how to add a `TextWatcher` to your edittexts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use `addTextChangedListener()` on edittext.

Check this link - [android on Text Change Listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20824634/android-on-text-change-listener)

Hope it will help you!

Comment: Have an issue with it.

Comment: which one? Post your issue in your existing question as an update