# when setText on editText TextWatcher.onTextChanged not called

Tags: java, android, inner-classes, android-textwatcher

Whenever `EditText` string is changed, `onTextChanged` is called.

Now when I start a new `Activity` and send data through `Bundle`, `onTextChanged` is not called.

```
if( getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    int value = -1;

    if(b != null)
        value = b.getInt("key");
    edit1.setText("Mywords:");
}
```

How can I call it ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So here's the modified version of your code. The idea is to set the text in the `EditText` after you add a `TextWatcher` on it.

```
if( getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    int value = -1;

    if(b != null)
        value = b.getInt("key");

    // Add  the TextWatcher here
    edit1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "before text changed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "on text changed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "after text changed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    // Now the set the value in your EditText
    edit1.setText("Mywords:");
}
```

Comment: Working Fine. Thanks

Comment: Good to know that helped!

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you are subscribing with `TextWatcher` before `setText` called.

Comment: you mean implementing TextWatcher class?

Comment: I mean that call to `edit1.addTextChangedListener` should be prior to `edit1.setText`.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, the method `addTextChangedListener` is not called for me.

However the method `doBeforeTextChanged`, `doOnTextChanged` and `doAfterTextChanged` worked perfectly :

```
amountTextField.doBeforeTextChanged { text, start, count, after ->
    Log.d(TAG, "beforeTextChange.") // OK, called
}
amountTextField.doOnTextChanged { text, start, before, count ->
    Log.d(TAG,  "onTextChanged.") // OK, called
}
amountTextField.doAfterTextChanged {
    Log.d(TAG, "afterTextChanged.") // OK, called
}
amountTextField.addTextChangedListener {
    object:  TextWatcher {
        override fun beforeTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {
            Log.d(TAG, "beforeTextChange.") // NOK, not called
        }

        override fun onTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {
            Log.d(TAG,  "onTextChanged.") // NOK, not called
        }

        override fun afterTextChanged(p0: Editable?) {
            Log.d(TAG,  "onTextChanged.") // NOK, not called
        }

    } }
```

By the way, the result was always the same : whether I set any text to my EidtText or not, whether after or before I set any text.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
edit1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                      int count, int after) {
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                  int before, int count) {
        }
    });
```

Reference: [android on Text Change Listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20824634/android-on-text-change-listener)

Comment: i already used it in the same way, u mean every time it change text using setText i have to create inner class every time?

Comment: no, you don't have to create the inner class every time, please, give us your code to can help you.