# How to make a custom Data Picker like Date Picker in Android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

How to make a custom Data Picker like Date Picker in Android so that I can get data (int data) by custom input or by using the buttons (- & +) so that it become easy for user to enter larger value !!
Has anyone any idea how to implement this?
please provide example, code snippet if possible.

I want to make like this

```
left - Button
middle - EditText
right - Button
```

I want Like this image--

[image: Like This..]

This is the example of Date Picker in Android:-

[image: Android Picker example]

Comment: Please help, anyone???

Comment: How about number picker? https://android--examples.blogspot.com/2015/05/how-to-use-numberpicker-in-android.html

Comment: that would do the thing for me , thanks Distwo

Comment: You can answer my question so that I can accept your answer and it could help others too..

Comment: Can I use TextWatcher as suggested below by @Nobody

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[then try this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20824665/5540205)

try on text changed listener as described in the link to update the variable whenever user changes the edit text, then variable will hold the changed value and so you can use your method to change values of that variable

Comment: can you provide code snippet according to my question?

Answer (score 1):

- Design a layout as you want with two buttons and one edittext in middle
- Then give one button addition funtionality and other substraction functionality

Follow little code snippet, provided below

```
addButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
public void onClick(){
   int valueInEditText = Integer.parseInt(etReference.getText().toString());
   etReference.setText(String.valueOf(valueInEditText + 1));
}
});
```

Similaryly, do it for substration button.

> **Note**: Do validation if you don't want negative values.

Comment: This will not work here as I'd already tried the same, if you update the value of EditText manually by entering any value how will it update the value of variable holding the integer value of EditText as soon as we finished typing

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use the `NumberPicker` which will allow you to select any value.

It's not the same look but it might work for you:
https://android--examples.blogspot.com/2015/05/how-to-use-numberpicker-in-android.html

Comment: is there any other way to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

After reading through various posts, examples, articles and Android documentation I found solution to my own question, It can be achieved by two ways:

> 1. First by using `NumberPicker`
> 2. Secondly by adding `TextChangedListener` to the `EditText`

Here is the code how I achieved it :

```
int noOfCups = 2;
EditText editTextNoOfCups;

editTextNoOfCups = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text_no_of_cups);
        editTextNoOfCups.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                if(s.length() != 0) {
                    Log.e("pss", String.valueOf(s));
                    noOfCups = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(s));
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {


            }
        });
```

Here is the link to official Android documentation :

- [TextWatcher | Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html)