# How can I move to another activity just entering 6 digits pin without clicking any button

Tags: android

I am recently working on android at initial phase. In my app I want to add a login page with 6 digits. after entering 6 digits correct pin user can go to homepage. I don't know which methods should I use or how can I do so. It will be my pleasure to get some help on this.

Comment: Show us some code

Answer (score 0):

You Have to try some code and ask if some error is occurred. StckOverflow is palace to clarify technical doubts .not a place to ask for opinion. Try to change your questioning pattern.

You have to use **TextWatcher()** for achieve this.

Refer the Below Links:

[TexWatcher fo Android](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html)

[TextChangerListener Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20824634/android-on-text-change-listener)