# Changing the text in addTextChangedListener listener of edit text in android gives error

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext, android-textinputedittext

- Is it not possible to change the text of `EditText` in
  `afterTextChanged`
- It gives the error below
- Is there a specific way to change the text

**code:**

```
inputEmail.addTextChangedListener(object :TextWatcher{
            override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
                inputEmail.setText("123456")
            }

            override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
            }

            override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
            }

        })
```

**Error:**

```
at com.caring2u.organizer.ui.fragments.screen.FrgBookingDetails$setEditTextListeners$4.afterTextChanged(FrgBookingDetails.kt:256)
        at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:9605)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:5496)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:5343)
        at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:113)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:5300)
```

Comment: What type is the Error? Is it Error or Exception?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing `EditText` in `TextWatcher` is not good idea at all.

When you setting `text` to `editText` your `TextWatcher` will call again .

Note:- And it will goes in **infinite loop**.

**Solution for this:-**

Use string value as a result in `TextWacher` and change your `ExitText` outside text-watcher.

Using `TextView` you can do like this .....

Create `TextView` in you layout like below.

```
<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_phone"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/border_edittext"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:singleLine="true" />



            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_phone"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/border_edittext"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:singleLine="true" />



    </FrameLayout>
```

and use `textWatcher` and Update your `TextView` text inside `onTextChange()` method

**Another Solution** :- Create XMl like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/code"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/border_edittext"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text=""
        android:singleLine="true" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/mobile"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/border_edittext"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:singleLine="true" />


</LinearLayout>
```

and update your `editText` with `id` **code** in your `textWatcher` of your `editText` with `id` **mobile**.

Comment: This seems true to me, not sure why this answer is getting negative votes.

Comment: Thats Exactly what is happening, But what is a workaround for this or is it not possible ?

Comment: If you're always setting your text to the same value, you could check in your text watcher to not set it if it's already at the correct value

Comment: @TFennis Some people are here to demotivate people. Who just down-vote and never mention why they did. We will not do anything in it.

Comment: @Devrath what you trying to achieve? Please share may we can help in it.

Comment: @SushilKumar .... I am changing a value in edit text, It is a phone no field .... Once someone modifies it, i need to append it with `+70` code along with the value user entered

Comment: try this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/20824665/5305430 or i have another one using TextView