# How to make TextInputLayout with two edit fields and only one hint?

Tags: android, android-layout

Additional constraints: both edit fields are placed to each other horizontally  and the hint is long enough to be above them

Long enough hint above two edit fields

=======          ==================

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pI0CE.png)

Comment: Well that should be a text view then on the top...

Comment: @Kannan_SJD 4 in this case the hint behavior is missing

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible for `TextInputLayout` to have 2 `EditText` as children. Doing this throws you an `InflateException` like this :

> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #xxx: We already
>   have an EditText, can only have one

So I assume that it's a Material Design guideline, and having one `TextInputLayout` with 2 `EditText` is anti-pattern to google's recommandations.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Only one hint above two edit fields"
        android:textSize="20dp"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/et1"
            />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/et2"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

If you ant to hide the `TextView`, you can use a [`TextChangedListener`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20824634/android-on-text-change-listener) and set the `Visibilty` to `INVISIBLE` if the text equals `""`.

Comment: thank you very much but it is not possible to simulate hint behavior: smaller text when field is inactive and larger when active

Comment: You can just change the TextView size.