# Android - Set EditText Bold / Italic / Underline for the future text

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-typeface

I want to apply the Text Formatting Options to the EditText. I am able to apply all the formating such as Bold, Italic, Underline, Strike-Through, BulletPoint when the text is selected. But, I want to apply the formatting to the future text that the user will type.

I used the  `mEditText.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD)` / `mEditText.setTypeface(null, Typeface.ITATIC)`, but it makes entire EditText Bold / Italic.

I want to make it Bold / Italic only to the text that will be typed after Bold / Italic button is clicked.

There are some similar questions but none of them have the answers to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use spans.

```
editText.doAfterTextChanged() {...
        when(selectedStyle) {
               Italic -> {
                      val spannable = SpannableString(text)
                      spannable.setSpan(Spans.Italic, styleStart, text.length, Spannable.EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
                }
         }
}
```

This article should help you 
https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/spantastic-text-styling-with-spans-17b0c16b4568

And this question should help you with the text listener
[android on Text Change Listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20824634/android-on-text-change-listener)

When the user press the button for changing the style then save the text lenght so in the `TextWatcher` after the text change you apply the style selected.

Maybe you should consider looking for some WYSIWYG library around.

Comment: Thank You ! It worked Perfectly. Just a small change instead of using the Spannable.Inclusive_EXCLUSIVE flag, you should use the  Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE flag, so that it starts making it BOLD / ITALIC from the current character. In case of Spannable.Inclusive_EXCLUSIVE, it makes the entire word BOLD / ITALIC.

Comment: then it should be `EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE` text length is 1 position more than the characters indexes, so it would be index out of bound

Comment: Setting flag to EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE  and  SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE both are throwing the Exception. java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: setSpan (35 ... 34) has end before start

Comment: Also, Could you tell me how to make the future text normal after user clicks the Normal Text Button? I tried the TypeFace.Normal option, but its not workng

Comment: You have to keep using spans `setSpans` or `removeSpans` spans are stackable you can have as many as you want to, read the article I share.

Answer (score -2):

**For only Bold :**

```
editText.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT,Typeface.BOLD)
```

*For only Italic :*

```
editText.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT,Typeface.ITALIC)
```

***For Bold and Italic Both,***

```
editText.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT,Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC)
```