# KeyListener on EditText in Android :

Tags: android

I have a editText and I want its input type only number(float). When a  user write some code(less than 2 &&  greater than 4) I want replace their value into it.

Comment: Use textwatcher

Comment: Does this answer your question? [android on Text Change Listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20824634/android-on-text-change-listener)