# Android : How to get the textview value and compare

Tags: android, if-statement, textview

Iam a newbie So
How to get the number value of textview and compare it that if it less than a 100 for example some other textview text changes to whatever i want ????

for example that if {textview1 < 25 || > 100}
i want to change the textview2 text to be "Hello"
else textview2 text "Goodbye"

Iam using fragment Activity

Comment: Does this answer your question? [android on Text Change Listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20824634/android-on-text-change-listener)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be something like this

```
textview2.Text = if (textview1.Text.ToInt() < 25 || textview1.Text.ToInt() > 100) "Hello" else "Goodbye"
```

Comment: android studio gives me red color on .Text , also i am in fragment activity